# Formato de imagen en CSS

Tags: css, image-view

Estoy intentando darle formato a tres imágenes que originalmente tienen tamaños muy diferentes. La idea es que cada imagen esté debajo de otra y formen un bloque vertical, además, que estas tengan un color de fondo (#5a6f99), el cual, se extienda por toda la página. Sin embargo, tengo la duda de cómo puedo lograr hacerlo en CSS (el archivo HTML no debe ser modificado). Lo que muestro en CSS genera un color de fondo en cada contenido pero no abarca toda la página y no tiene el color de manera continua. Además, deseo que las tres imagenes inicien debajo y de lado izquierdo de mi imagen de fondo que coloqué en el  <kbd>header</kbd>  de CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ultimate Frisbee - Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hw1.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Ultimate Frisbee</h1>
        <nav>
            <a href="index.html" class = "active">Home</a>
            <a href="teams.html">Teams</a>
            <a href="history.html">History</a>
            <a href="http://www.usaultimate.org/index.html" target="_blank">USA Ultimate</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
        <main>
            <aside class = "left">
            <a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AUltimate_Frisbee%2C_Jul_2009_-_17.jpg"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/Ultimate_Frisbee%2C_Jul_2009_-_19.jpg" alt="Creative Common Ultimate Photo" title="By Ed Yourdon [CC BY-SA 2.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0)], via Wikimedia Commons"/> </a>

            <a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AUltimate_Frisbee_Colorado_Cup_2005.jpg"><img alt="Ultimate Frisbee Colorado Cup 2005" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7d/Ultimate_Frisbee_Colorado_Cup_2005.jpg/512px-Ultimate_Frisbee_Colorado_Cup_2005.jpg"/></a>


            <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/paradisecoastie/15409853738/" title="Ultimate Frisbee"><img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3948/15409853738_7dbfbfbac7_k.jpg"  alt="Ultimate Frisbee"></a>
        </aside>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Verdana', sans-serif;
}



header {
    background-image: url("../images/flywheel.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    
    
    
}

header h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #faf0d4;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

header a {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: rgba(190, 194, 204, 0.6);
    color: #1f2638;
    font-size: 19px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1rem 4.5rem;
    margin: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;

}


aside a {
    float:left;
    background-color: #5a6f99;
    
    
    
}

.left img {
    
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    object-fit: cover;
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    border: 5px #191c1a solid;
    border-radius: 25px;
    
   
}


.right h2 {
    font-size: 35px;
}

.right p {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.right table {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Para poner el color de fondo de toda la página puedes utilizar `background-color` en `body`

```
body {
  background-color: #5a6f99;
}
```

Para hacer que tus imágenes estén alineadas a la izquierda en forma de columna puedes utilizar `float: left` en `aside`. En tu CSS estás utilizandolo en `aside a`, es decir, estás indicando que los elementos `a` dentro de `aside` estén alineados a la izquierda, pero en ninguna parte de tu CSS estás alineando el `aside` a la izquierda, tienes que agregar esto (Y no sería necesario el `aside a`)

```
aside{
    float: left;
}
```

Te dejo un ejemplo con los cambios para que revises si funciona como deseas

```css
* {
    margin: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Verdana', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #5a6f99;
}

header {
    background-image: url("../images/flywheel.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    
    
    
}

header h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #faf0d4;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

header a {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: rgba(190, 194, 204, 0.6);
    color: #1f2638;
    font-size: 19px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1rem 4.5rem;
    margin: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;

}


aside{
    float: left;
}

.left img {
    
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    object-fit: cover;
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    border: 5px #191c1a solid;
    border-radius: 25px;
    
   
}


.right h2 {
    font-size: 35px;
}

.right p {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.right table {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <header>
        <h1>Ultimate Frisbee</h1>
        <nav>
            <a href="index.html" class = "active">Home</a>
            <a href="teams.html">Teams</a>
            <a href="history.html">History</a>
            <a href="http://www.usaultimate.org/index.html" target="_blank">USA Ultimate</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
        <main>
            <aside class = "left">
            <a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AUltimate_Frisbee%2C_Jul_2009_-_17.jpg"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/Ultimate_Frisbee%2C_Jul_2009_-_19.jpg" alt="Creative Common Ultimate Photo" title="By Ed Yourdon [CC BY-SA 2.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0)], via Wikimedia Commons"/> </a>

            <a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AUltimate_Frisbee_Colorado_Cup_2005.jpg"><img alt="Ultimate Frisbee Colorado Cup 2005" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7d/Ultimate_Frisbee_Colorado_Cup_2005.jpg/512px-Ultimate_Frisbee_Colorado_Cup_2005.jpg"/></a>


            <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/paradisecoastie/15409853738/" title="Ultimate Frisbee"><img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3948/15409853738_7dbfbfbac7_k.jpg"  alt="Ultimate Frisbee"></a>
        </aside>
```

Comment: Buen día @DanielRico, es importante mantener una pregunta por publicación para que otros usuarios puedan encontrar las respuestas fácilmente. Para activar los línk que están siendo visitados puedes revisar [este artículo](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_active_element.asp)

Comment: @DanielRico, si la respuesta resolvió tu problema por favor no olvides aceptarla, eso ayudará a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares. Al mismo tiempo ayudamos a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas.